# how to rotate a graph around a center point in python

Tags: python, geometry

I want to turn a rectangular graph (chart) into circular chart like this one:

[image: radial line graph]

Now, I'm not really looking to transform an actual graphical chart, I'm really just trying to transform the underlying data: the (x,y) coordinates.

My data set is at equal time intervals so it's just a list of y coordinates like this (where x is implied to be increasing at an even rate):

```
[11,16,12,14,13,12,13,10...]
```

and I want to wrap it around the center like in the image so that it mutates to look something like this: (just estimating here):

[(0,11),(3,14),(8,8),(13,4)...]

I don't know, I guess that makes more of an oval or something, anyway, the point is I just want to wrap the end of the rectangular graph around so it comes back to `x = 0` and then have new coordinates as (x,y) pairs where (0,0) is the center of the circle.

I have no idea what this kind of transformation is called or if there are python packages that already do this. And again, I'm not looking for the actual plotting software such as something like this: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html I just want a function that takes the points, does the math on then and returns new coordinates.

Does anyone know of a package that does that?

or if one doesn't exist does anyone know what kind of math I'd have to do, or what the formula is to do this?

UPDATE: response to answer.

Thank you for your answers and direction, Reblochon Masque and Ghasem Naddaf, you have both suggested wrapping it around the polar plot. I've tried to implement your advice, but have been unable to get what I want. To simplify things I've change the demo dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from math import pi

ydata = [10,11,12,13,16,13,12,11]
xdata = [0,  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.show()

data_len = len(ydata)
max_y = max(ydata)
DESIRED_MAP_RADIUS = 10.0
new_data = {'x': [n * 2 * pi / data_len for n in range(data_len)] ,
            'y': [y/max_y*DESIRED_MAP_RADIUS for y in ydata]}
print(new_data)

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(new_data['y'], new_data['x'])
ax.set_rmax(DESIRED_MAP_RADIUS)
ax.set_rticks([2, 4, 6, 8])  # less radial ticks
ax.set_rlabel_position(-22.5)  # get radial labels away from plotted line
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

This result prints out the following `new_data`:

> {'x': [0.0, 0.7853981633974483, 1.5707963267948966, 2.356194490192345,
>   3.141592653589793, 3.9269908169872414, 4.71238898038469, 5.497787143782138], 'y': [6.25, 6.875, 7.5, 8.125, 10.0, 8.125, 7.5, 6.875]}

and the images it prints are these:

[image: original chart]

[image: polar]

notice how the polar representation isn't what I'm looking for. the data goes up to a peak then back down. if I were to hand draw this round a circular graph it would look something like this:

[image: estimation]

See how the points away from the center become the Y distance? but the X's go from `range(0,8)` to a set of positive and negative numbers rotating around the center. am I going to need to use `np.sin()` somehow in order to get this result? It seems the polar chart isn't sufficient.

Comment: Modulo operator.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I'm sorry, I'm really not good with math, can you elaborate a bit? I think I understand using y as a distance from the origin, but the x->[0,2*pi] I don't understand. x is one number how can I map it to a list of [0, 2*pi], and 2pi wouldn't that just give me an increasing x? can you elaborate a little? besides that I need the underlying data and I don't know how to get that out of pyplot, I only know how to render the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is related to this post:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260096/find-the-coordinates-of-a-point-on-a-circle

```
x = radius * np.sin(θ)
y = radius * np.cos(θ)
```

The `radius` is your `y` variable, and your `θ` must come from dividing a circle by the number of points in your dataset.

```
theta = 360 / len(ydata)
```

To verify the resulting point is really the correct distance away from the center (y) you can follow the formula `sqr(x) + sqr(y) = sqr(r)` and you'll see it's the correct distance at the correct angle.

So the code looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from math import pi

ydata = [10,11,12,13,16,13,12,11]

#plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
#plt.show()

def wrap_around(radii):
    thetas = [i * (360 / len(radii)) for i in range(0, len(radii))]
    xs = [(radius * np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta))) for radius, theta in zip(radii, thetas)]
    ys = [(radius * np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta))) for radius, theta in zip(radii, thetas)]
    print(thetas, len(thetas))
    print(xs, len(xs))
    print(ys, len(ys))
    return xs,ys

x,y = wrap_around(ydata)
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
from math import pi
ydata = [11,16,12,14,13,12,13,10]
data_len = len(ydata)
max_y = max(ydata)
DESIRED_MAP_RADIUS = 100.0
new_data = {'x': [n * 2 * pi / data_len for n in range(data_len)] ,
            'y': [y/max_y*DESIRED_MAP_RADIUS for y in ydata]
           }
print(new_data)
```